# Python ndarray dtype and buffer question - it returns different values

Tags: python, buffer, numpy-ndarray, dtype

so I am trying to create a numpy darray object with the following code:

```
a = np.ndarray(shape=(3,3),dtype='float32',buffer=np.array([[100,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
```

and this returns the following:

```
[[1.4e-43 0.0e+00 2.8e-45]
 [0.0e+00 4.2e-45 0.0e+00]
 [5.6e-45 0.0e+00 7.0e-45]]
```

why does it return the different values than what I've specified?

Seems like float32 is changing things, since when dtype='int' like:

```
a = np.ndarray(shape=(3,3),dtype='int',buffer=np.array([[100,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
```

this returns the correct things like:

```
[[100   2   3]
 [  4   5   6]
 [  7   8   9]]
```

why it doesn't work when dtype='float32'?

Comment: Because you are passing a buffer that has dtype=float32... why did you expect it to work any differently? Why are you using the `numpy.ndarray` constructor to begin with? Why not `np.array([[100,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype='float32')`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current state **a** is nothing but a array of random numbers with dtype 'float32'.
The error in first case is because of mismatch in dtype you provided **dtype='float32'** and the default **dtype='int64'** for np.array().
To get the required result you should add argument in np.array() dtype='float32'

```
    a = np.ndarray(size=(3, 3), dtype='float32' buffer=np.array([[100, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype='float32')

    [[100., 2., 3.]
     [4., 5., 6.]
     [7., 8., 9.]]
```

Remember the dataType will be float for **a** that's why we have decimal in the end.

And second case works because of dtype='int' which is default dtype for np.array(). So datatype matches and it works.